# how to set application pool idle timeout programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to set the idle timeout of application pool programmatically so that the session timeout set by the user in the web page will match that of the application pool?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On IIS7+ you can use the Microsoft.Web.Administration library

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

```
ApplicationPool.ProcessModel.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero;
```

Answer (score 1):

On IIS7 you could use Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly, look at ApplicationPool class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

I think that property that you are looking for is

ApplicationPool.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Time

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpoolrecycling%28v=VS.90%29.aspx